# Get parent element whose n number of child has same class using xpath or css in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I want to find element div with class=parent-class whose three children should have same class=no-data using xpath or css selector.

i.e all three > 3rd, 4th & 5th child div of parent class should have 'no-data' class.
example:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="parent-class">
       <div class="child-1">child1</div>
       <div class="child-2">child2</div>
       <div class="no-data">NA</div>
       <div class="data">xyz</div>
       <div class="data">ijk</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent-class">
       <div class="child-1">child1</div>
       <div class="child-2">child2</div>
       <div class="no-data">NA</div>
       <div class="no-data">NA</div>
       <div class="no-data">NA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent-class">
       <div class="child-1">child1</div>
       <div class="child-2">child2</div>
       <div class="data">abc</div>
       <div class="data">xyz</div>
       <div class="data">ijk</div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent-class">
       <div class="child-1">child1</div>
       <div class="child-2">child2</div>
       <div class="no-data">NA</div>
       <div class="no-data">NA</div>
       <div class="data">ijk</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @JeremyMoritz any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Tried below solution: it works for me

```
//div[contains(@class,'parent-class') and div[@class='no-data'][1] and div[@class='no-data'][2] and div[@class='no-data'][3]]
                                      or 
//div[contains(@class,'parent-class') and (div[@class='no-data'][1] and div[@class='no-data'][2] and div[@class='no-data'][3])]
```

Though looking for some better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use below given xpath to trace your required elements.

```
//div[@class='main']//child::div[2]//
child::div[@class='no-data'][1]

//div[@class='main']//child::div[2]//
child::div[@class='no-data'][2]

//div[@class='main']//child::div[2]//
child::div[@class='no-data'][3]
```

Comment: They are 3 diff locators want to locate parent element using only one locator

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
//div[@class='parent-class'][not(div[(position()>2 and position()<6) and .[@class != 'no-data']])]
```

Comment: it works assuming if 3rd element is having class no-data means 4th &5th element will have same class as well.Also, it return child not parent.

Comment: tweaked above xpath to get parent with previously mentioned assumption //div[3][@class='na-value']/parent::div

Comment: Okay, I meant three child elements to have same class(3 out of 5). i.e in above example I want to get parent element whose child element 3rd, 4th and 5th is having same class.

Comment: @KINZ  so just to be clear: in your html above, only the 2nd parent-classmeets the condition and the desired output is its name - div?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your requirement it should be something like:

```
//div[@class='parent-class' and count(descendant::div[@class='no-data'])=3]
```

where:

- [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) - is XPath [Axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes) returning children of the current node and their children
- [count()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/count) - is XPath [Function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) returning the number of nodes matching the expression

Therefore above expression will match [div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) tag having 3 children with `no-data` class